# После анимации в WPF C# некорректно работает GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

В программе при нажатии соответствующей кнопки происходит скрытие столбца, при повторном нажатии - раскрывается. 
До скрытия/раскрытия с помощью GridSplitter можно спокойно менять ширину столбца, содержимое (Border, в нем вложенный грид и т.д.) также растягивается или сжимается. 
Однако после выполнения анимации GridSplitter растягивает и сжимает столбец, но содержимое размер не меняет размера, Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

Код функции раскрытия столбца:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.From = 0;
MainPanel.MinWidth = 250;
animation.To = MainPanel.MinWidth;
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
animation.Completed += Animation_Completed;
RootMenu.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, animation);
```

Код скрытия столбца:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.From = MainPanel.ActualWidth;
animation.To = 0;
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
MainPanel.MinWidth = 0;
MainPanel.Width = GridLength.Auto;
RootMenu.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, animation);
```

MainPanel - имя столбца
RootMenu - имя Border.

Что и где необходимо подправить, чтобы после действия анимации GridSplitter работал корректно?

Есть предположение, что после анимации у Border выставляется фиксированная ширина и по этому он не расширяется. Как это исправить, понять не могу

Answer (score 3):

[Решение проблемы](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level15/15_5.php)

Проблема решена путем удаления объекта анимации по ее завершении, обработав событие Completed объекта анимации.